# Allowing HEAD request for custom API in Azure Mobile Services (with NodeJs backend)

Tags: node.js, azure, azure-mobile-services

Can anyone give me an example on adding permission to the HEAD HTTP request to a specific custom API in Azure Mobile Services? I want to create an endpoint for receiving a HEAD request t from thrid parties.

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Currently HEAD requests are not supported in API (or table) requests in the node.js runtime for Azure Mobile Services. Please consider creating a new feature request at http://feedback.azure.com/forums/216254-mobile-services.

Comment: This can easily be implemented in Node.js but it's unfortunately not possible due to accessibility constraints. It will also be nice to have more control over the lower level defaults.